# Access string resources from Android SDK

Tags: android, android-resources

Recently I found, that `android.R.string` contains few useful localized strings like "OK", "Yes", "No" and they are accessible in java code with `getResources().getString(android.R.string.yes)`

But Android SDK contains much more localized strings. They are located in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-25/data/res/values-$LANG/string.xml`

For example, I want to use following string

```
    <string name="gpsNotifTicker">Location request from <xliff:g id="name">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

Is there are any way to do it, beside copying and pasting string from each file?

`android:text="@android:string/gpsNotifTicker"` in xml gives me "Resource is not public" error

`getString(android.R.string.gpsNotifTicker, name)` in java gives me "Unresolved reference"

Also, I've tried to add sdk resources to source sets in build.gradle

```
android {
//.....
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main.resources.srcDirs += '/Users/rostopira/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res'
    }
}
```

But strings still not accessible

Comment: Any luck? I am trying to access these same resources to use in instrumentation testing, to detect the permission dialog options (deny, allow) in various languages.

Comment: @Petermonteer yeah, I've found lib for that a long time after this question, but actually didn't attempt to use it, however you may try: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Comment: Could be silly, but have you tried to remove the "android." before the "R" ? And remove the "import android.R" if exists?

Comment: @MarcoOttina what's the point? It will reference app's own resources, instead of system ones

Comment: The point is that this simple modifications resolved my issue. I don't know why, but the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You may reference system resources with `@android` specifier:

```
android:text="@android:string/SOME_RESOURCE"
```

Comment: This doesn't works with example. Works only for simple strings like "Yes" and "No". Also, I need this string in Java code

Comment: I guess it's just the autocompletition is not working. Otherwise if you write manually it would not promt you with error. [See screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/qwUpDpE.png)

Comment: I've tried. It says `"@android:string/gpsNotifTicker" resource is not public`

Comment: That means, that you should not rely on that resource, because it may be changed or entirely removed in upcoming APIs.

Comment: that's not an answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be `main.res.srcDirs` instead of `main.resources.srcDirs`.
However, there is A LOT of resources, so it causes mess and Android Studio hangs.
Wouldn't recommend =)